# How to correctly show contact names in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

Most of my contacts are businesses, I was able to find the field "Archive as" in my Google Contacts which helped in organizing them.

However when entering a contact in Gmail, it still shows the person name and not the business name, this created some confusion since who receive it might think the message was not intended for him/her.

I want to show the business name to make everyone happy, I tried removing the person name but Gmail try to guess for example by pulling data from their Google profile or by other means.

I could make a group for every businesses listing all the employee I usually have contact with, but I don't think I could have a group of groups.

Answer (score 1):

- go to **https://contacts.google.com/**
- select a contact and edit it:

  [image]
- in the field **First name** enter desired (display) business name

  [image]